# Celery multi starts with 1 or more processes

Tags: python, process, celery

When I run celery with 3 workers as follows:

```
celery -A tasks multi start default, high, low -Q:1 default -c:1 6 -Q:2 high -c:2 2 -Q:3 low -c:3 2 -l info -E --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n.log
```

ps aux | grep 'celery worker'

```
vagrant   2447 14.0  7.3 262216 36708 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2458 15.5  7.2 259656 36216 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n low,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q low -c 1 --logfile=/var/log/celery/low,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/low,.pid
vagrant   2468  0.0  6.4 261192 32380 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2469  0.0  6.4 261192 32372 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2470  0.0  6.4 261192 32372 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2471  0.0  6.4 261192 32372 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2472  0.0  6.4 261192 32376 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2473  0.0  6.4 261192 32376 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n default,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q default -c 6 --logfile=/var/log/celery/default,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/default,.pid
vagrant   2475 13.0  7.2 259656 36236 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n high@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q high -c 1 --logfile=/var/log/celery/high.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/high.pid
vagrant   2480  0.0  6.3 258588 31920 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n low,@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q low -c 1 --logfile=/var/log/celery/low,.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/low,.pid
vagrant   2481  0.0  6.4 258976 32304 ?        S    05:20   0:00 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery worker -E -n high@server -A box_monitor -l info -Q high -c 1 --logfile=/var/log/celery/high.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/high.pid
```

10 is expected process number but it's 11. Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first process (2447) is the one that started the other 10 and is controlling them. It won't do any actual work, the other 10 processes are the workers doing actual processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can you tell that? Sometimes it creates 3 more process.

Comment: I can tell because that's how you usually implement "multi-worker" systems. You have a main controller process that spawns X worker processes. Why it would create 3 extra processes I don't know.